# Angular JS JQuery modal not showing

Tags: jquery, html, css, angularjs

I have the following setup:

- Page called `admin.php` where I load all the scripts and CSS
- On that page there is `<ng-view>` route to show the correct content based on what is clicked
- Userlist is created in `editUser.php` where an `ng-repeat` list all the content of a $http request
- Above the list there is an ADD button, which should show a modal
- When I click, I can see the modal is loaded (chrome developer), but I can't see it...

```
<div ng-controller="userCTRL">
<div align="right">
    <button type="button" name="add_button" ng-click="addData()" class="btn btn-success">Add</button>
</div>



<!-- MODAL DIV FOR SUCCESS -->
<div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible" ng-show="success" >
    <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">&times;</a>
    {{successMessage}}
</div>
<div class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" id="crudmodal">
 <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
     <div class="modal-content">
      <form method="post" ng-submit="submitForm()">
         <div class="modal-header">
           <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
           <h4 class="modal-title">{{modalTitle}}</h4>
         </div>
         <div class="modal-body">
          <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible" ng-show="error" >
      <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">&times;</a>
      {{errorMessage}}
     </div>
          <div class="form-group">
      <label>Enter First Name</label>
      <input type="text" name="first_name" ng-model="first_name" class="form-control" />
     </div>
     <div class="form-group">
      <label>Enter Last Name</label>
      <input type="text" name="last_name" ng-model="last_name" class="form-control" />
     </div>
         </div>
         <div class="modal-footer">
          <input type="hidden" name="hidden_id" value="{{hidden_id}}" />
          <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-info" value="{{submit_button}}" />
           <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          </div>
         </form>
     </div>
   </div>
</div> <!-- end of Modal div -->
</div> <!-- end of controller -->
```

This is the `editUser.php`
The controller looks like:

```
app.controller('userCTRL', function($scope, $http) {

    $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: '../auth/getUserData.php'
        })
        .then(function(response) {
            $scope.namesData = response.data;
            console.log(response.data);

        })
    $scope.openModal = function() {
        var modal_popup = angular.element('#crudmodal');
        console.log('openModal function');
        $('#crudmodal').show();
        //modal_popup.open();
    };

    $scope.closeModal = function() {
        var modal_popup = angular.element('#crudmodal');
        modal_popup.modal('hide');
    };
    $scope.addData = function() {
        console.log('addData function');
        $scope.modalTitle = 'Add Data';
        $scope.submit_button = 'Insert';
        $scope.openModal();
    };
});
```

And the admin page is like this:

```
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-modal/0.9.2/jquery.modal.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.8/angular.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.8/angular-route.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" /> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" />

</head>

<body ng-app="myApp" >

<div class="menu">
    <p><a href="#/!">Main</a>
    <a href="#!users">USERS</a>
    <a href="logout.php">logout</a></p>
</div>

<div ng-view></div>

<script src="/app/admin.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

There are no errors shown and like I mentioned, the code changes and adds the modal...I just can't see it...
Anyone an idea?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, really stupid, but I forgot to load the bootstrap.js !!! 
Now it is working...

thanks!